# Custom SharePoint 2010 forms

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Am I required to use InfoPath to create custom forms for SharePoint 2010, or can I create them using Visual Studio? For example, when a Task is being edited, I want to be able to either edit the form, or create one from scratch.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

InfoPath or SharePoint Designer are the main tools to use when building custom content to run in SharePoint.

Hard to say which route is best for you without knowing the spec of the forms but I'd recommend you have a play with each.  The Designer route can be more powerful if you're happy diving in to the rather messy markup that SharePoint spews out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit the form that is displayed when a task is added / edited, you should go for SharePoint designer instead of InfoPath and apply the required customizations to the relevant associated page of the targeted list (eg : newform.aspx) by playing with a dataform web part.

Otherwise, you can create a user control and wrap it in a webpart to manage the task creation / edition the way you want. You can then place that webpart at the most relevant location(s). You can then make the "storage" list hidden so people will not fall back on the default form templates to add / edit items (unless they figure out the url, but you can remove all permissions and run with elevation if it's an issue).

Comment: Thanks. I've only been looking at SharePoint for a day so am getting lost quickly. I've created a Workflow which is simply an approval process on the current item for a specific user. I believe I can get to the relevent form for my Workflow task (Workflow > Open task list > Forms > EditForm.aspx) however I am unable to edit the form. Is this a permissions issue? Thanks.

Comment: Ah! Workflow Task Forms? There is even an MSDN article for it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms550938.aspx (try editing the form with Sharepoint designer, you should be able to do so, otherwise it is a permissions issue)

Comment: The form I mentioned earlier seems to be the default task form for the entire site so isn't the one I want to edit. I can open the forms in the Form section of my Workflow, however that opens InfoPath 2010; is there a way I can edit the form without InfoPath?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own form for a custom list definition. Inside your list you have a file **schema.xml**. In the end you will find sth like this:

```
<Forms>
  <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
  <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
  <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
</Forms>
```

Then create files with those names inside list definition, make adjustments in **SharePointProjectItem.spdata** file (it's hidden) and there you have it.